# How do I start the Application Uploader on a Mac?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've written an app and I want to upload it to Apple for review and AppStore.

I've read that the Application Uploader is located at /Developer/Applications/Utilities.

However, I don't know what I should do with this information.

Where do I find or enter "/Developer" so that I can the move on to "/Applications"?

Finder? Launcher? Command prompt? XCode?

Comment: Click on the magnifying glass in the top-right corner of your Mac, then start to type Application Uploader and it should locate the app. Hit return or select it to open it :)

Comment: @Luke This does not work because Spotlight doesn't search inside applications. See my answer below why Application Loader is inside another application.

Comment: The request sounded to me that he wanted to use the Application Loader to submit an app; therefore to perform this, he wanted to know how to launch the app, which I stated. The app is located for me via the method I have described previously: http://i.imgur.com/aHpKP.jpg

Comment: I noticed that it is called Application Loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XCode 4 you don't need the Application Uploader anymore. Just select the device target (not the simulator), choose the menu Product - Archive.
This will result in a product in the archives section of your organizer (menu: Window-Organizer). Here you can have the app validated, and submitted.

BTW, /Developer is where XCode used to be, now XCode (4.3) is in /Applications/XCode, so that might be a little confusing.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open your xCode
2. On the menu bar go to  xCode-> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader

Answer (score 2):

Since an update of Xcode lately, the `/Developer` folder is not in use any more. You can find Application Loader and other apps within `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications`.

To open this folder, copy the path, open 'Go > Go to Folder' in Finder and paste the path in the popup. Or find Xcode in you Applications folder, right-click on it, press 'Show Package Contents' and navigate to the right subfolder.

Tip: for quick access to Application Loader (and the other apps, i.e., FileMerge, Icon Composer, and Instruments), you can create an alias to them and place these in your Applications folder. Or, if you use them very often, drag them to your Dock.